# How to remove duplicate combinations from an array in python

Tags: python, numpy

Supposed I have a list or a numpy array

```
[[3 6]
 [1 5]
 [2 3]
 [2 6]
 [0 4]
 [2 4]
 [0 2]]
```

since [3,6] and [2,3] occur, I want to remove a third possible combination of 2,3 and 6 which is [2,6].

similarily [0,4] and [2,4] occur, I want to remove a third possible combination of 0,2 and 4 which is [0,2]

Essentially from any possible combination of 3 numbers, only 2 combinations which occur first should remain, the other should be removed out.

The final output should be

```
[[3 6]
 [1 5]
 [2 3]
 [0 4]
 [2 4]]
```

Comment: Shouldn't `[2, 4]` be removed as well?

Comment: @Chris I believe `[2, 4]` can stay, since it'd only be a 'duplicate' in the way the OP has defined it if there exists another integer x such that `[x, 2]` and `[x, 4]` are also in the list even after the duplicates involving 0, 2 and 4 have already been removed.

Comment: @Chris `[2, 3]` and `[0, 4]` don't share any numbers, so `[2, 4]` is safe.  I think?

Comment: This is a specific and well-defined problem. I do not understand how this can be construed as to broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure there's probably a more efficient and elegant way to solve this problem (not to mention, I didn't even bother using numpy vectors for their performance). But here's a brute force solution using just list comprehension.

```
from itertools import combinations

data_list = [[3, 6], [1, 5], [2, 3], [2, 6], [0, 4], [2, 4], [0, 2]]

# doc for the combination function:
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations
all_triple_pairs = list(combinations(data_list, 3))

# obtain the unique set of digits in all possible combination of triples
digit_sets = [set(d for pair in trip for d in pair) for trip in all_triple_pairs]

# the duplicates occur only when there are 3 unique digits
dup_inds = [i for i, s in enumerate(digit_sets) if len(s)==3]

# get the actual triples of pairs with a duplicated pair element 
duplicates = [all_triple_pairs[i] for i in dup_inds]

# mark the last pair (as requested) in each duplicated triple for removal
pairs_to_remove = [trip[-1] for trip in duplicates]

answer = [pair for pair in data_list if pair not in pairs_to_remove]

for p in answer:
    print(p)

--------------------
[3, 6]
[1, 5]
[2, 3]
[0, 4]
[2, 4]
```